# Open Media File In External Player

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

Is there a way to make a browser open video links in an external player? Similar to how `mailto` links are handled.

Specifically, I'd like to be able to link to an `mp4` file but open an external player specified by the user. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just link to it.

Keep in mind that sometimes that "external player" though is the browser itself, and there's nothing you can/should do about this, if you want to go the "pure" route.

For *some* players, you could use an M3U file.  So, just a text file formatted like this:

```
#EXTM3U
https://example.com/your-video.mp4
```

Use `application/mpegurl` for the content type.

Comment: I need extended media controls, such as speeding up, skipping, bookmarks etc. I'm mainly thinking about VLC. I don't want to have to copy and paste links manually every time. Is there no way to enforce this? `mp4` is supported by virtually every browser.

Comment: @Nearoo Have you considered an M3U file?  It can consist of just two lines, one of `#EXTM3U`, and the next of the URL to your MP4.  I really don't recommend this, as I think very strongly that people should be able to use whatever player they want... but I don't know of any browsers that try to open the MP4 up on their own.

Comment: I have not. We're getting closer! This still prompts the user to download the m3u file, but once opened, it will stream what I want it to stream.

Comment: You must be confusing mp4 with another type, it's supported by [basically all browser](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mpeg4).

Comment: @Nearoo Sorry, I mistyped, I meant that I don't know any browsers that try to open up **M3U** on their own.

Comment: Ah no problem. Sadly the solution isn't good enough. I settled with a button that copies the URL of the video file into your clipboard, to paste into VLC. Thanks anyway.